# Combining iloc and loc

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine iloc and loc, is there possibility?

Specifically I would like to:

- give integer in the form (:train_size) for the rows values
- give a list with the column names for the column values (replacing [0,1] in the code below)

  training_set = dataset.iloc[:train_size,[0,1]].values

trying

```
training_set = dataset.loc[:train_size,[list_input_and_y_parameters]].values
```

gives error message

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on  with these indexers [4275] of

Is there a way to do that?

Many thanks

Comment: I believe we need more information to assert this with clarity. For example, we need to know how you `dataset` looks like, what are the columns and indexes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can chain this operation or use only `iloc` with [`Index.get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) for positions of columns in list:

```
training_set = dataset.iloc[:train_size].loc[:, ['col1','col2']].values
```

---

```
training_set = dataset.iloc[:train_size, df.columns.get_indexer(['col1','col2'])].values
```

Comment: I think using `Index.get_indexer` is the best options because it also work with assignment

Comment: Do you know if it is considered proper to use chained indexing for the first example?  The documentation discourages chained indexing such as, dfmi['one']['second'], but it doesn't cover chained loc's. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: @etotheipi While using chained loc's, I'm getting the same warning, so I assume it is not a proper way to do it.

Comment: @Garnagar - can you try `training_set = dataset.iloc[:train_size].loc[:, ['col1','col2']].copy()` ?

Comment: What a horribly convoluted method we need to follow to make something as simple as `df[0, 'col'] = 10` work! Pandas really needs to make it easier to assign to a particular row (by index) and a particular column (by name)

Answer (score 4):

As chaining `loc` and `iloc` can cause `SettingWithCopyWarning`, an option without a need to use `Index.get_indexer` could be (*assuming there are no duplicates in the index*):

```
training_set = dataset.loc[dataset.index[:train_size], ['col1','col2']].values
```